# How to find missing closing bracket in HTML tags?

Tags: html, atom-editor

Weird case from a project I recently took over.

There are some HTML tags that are missing their closing '>'
e.g.:

```
<div
  class="example"
</div>
```

This is currently not breaking anything in Chrome but when viewed in IE it has issues.

I've tracked down a number of mistakes with it (looked like copy paste work with an iron-ajax block) but would really like a tool that could help me find other places this is happening.

I currently use Atom but would be willing to use anything to track this down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the below package for Atom to validate HTML

1. https://atom.io/packages/w3c-validation
2. HTMLhint(https://github.com/tcarlsen/atom-htmlhint)
3. https://github.com/atom/bracket-matcher

Answer (score 1):

[HTML Tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/)? Or any of a number of other HTML validators or linters.